# repeated nginx ubuntu 16.04 error on update install

Tags: 16.04, apache2, dpkg, nginx

Every time I run `sudo apt-get update` an error is getting thrown regarding nginx.

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
nginx
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3.498 B of archives.
After this operation, 37,9 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package nginx.
(Reading database ... 542828 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nginx_1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4_all.deb ...
Unpacking nginx (1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) ...
Setting up nginx-full (1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) ...
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-full (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit   status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:
nginx depends on nginx-core (>= 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) | nginx-full    (>= 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) | nginx-light (>= 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) |   nginx-extras (>= 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4); however:
Package nginx-core is not installed.
Package nginx-full is not configured yet.
Package nginx-light is not installed.
Package nginx-extras is not installed.
nginx depends on nginx-core (<< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~) | nginx- full (<< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.10.0-  0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~) | nginx-extras (<< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~);  however:
Package nginx-core is not installed.
Package nginx-full is not configured yet.
Package nginx-light is not installed.
Package nginx-extras is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a   followup error from a previous failure.
                      Errors were encountered while processing:
nginx-full
nginx
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried to resolve as suggested in other posts without success:

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx
sudo apt-get -f install    # (as mentioned in this post)
```

```
$ systemctl status nginx.service
nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mo 2016-11-07 21:05:51 CET; 7min ago
Process: 10372 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

I also tried the following... as the error persists.

```
apt purge nginx
apt autoremove
apt install nginx
```

How many options do I have from here to get on the right track?

Should I try uninstalling/disabling apache2?

Comment: I believe the answer you are looking for is [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/764222/nginx-installation-error-in-ubuntu-16-04/805283#805283) in that you need to stop the apache service in order to install nginx

Answer (score 1):

Shutting down apache2 first before installing nginx should fix this problem.

stop apache2

```
sudo systemctl stop apache2.service
```

prevent apache2 to start at boot

```
sudo systemctl disable apache2.service
```

Reinstall nginx

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```